# what is the meaning of time this---His success was down to being in the right place at the right time

Tags: sentence, question-tags

what is the meaning of this---His success was down to being in the right place at the right time

Comment: what is the meaning of this--His success was down to being in the right place at the right time

Comment: i don;t understand this statement ... help me kaushik bhai

Comment: “Down to” was probably “due to” in the original.  With this change, a dictionary will be enough.

Comment: no dictionary describe that down to is equal to 'due to"

Comment: What do you think “down to” means, then?

Comment: Definition of **down to**
1: in a way that includes even (the smallest or least important part)
Source: [https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down%20to].    


Try using this in your sentence. Does it make sense?

Comment: i don't know... i m very confused

Comment: The meaning is 'may be reduced to'. In essence, the problem or the fact may be reduced to a single cause or effect. Interesting question - up-voted +1.

Comment: Your most [recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/491728/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-sentence-i-was-annoyed-by-mary-wanting-to-tell-eve) is attracting downvotes, and it's not difficult to understand why. You ***must*** explain what it is you don't understand. Identify the word or expression that is the obstacle, saying you don't understand an entire sentence is 1. not credible 2. vague

Comment: It would also be useful to know the name of the novel or textbook where you got these lines from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to really simplify it, in this case "down to." replaces the word because.

it is because he was in the right place at the right time that he was successfull.

it's just another way of writting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oxford Dictionary (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/):

"***be down to***

1) be attributable to (a particular factor or circumstance)

he claimed his problems were down to the media

2) be the responsibility of (a particular person)

it's down to you to make sure the boiler receives regular servicing

3) be left with only (the specified amount)

I'm down to my last few pounds"

I think the last meaning is appropriate.

Then your sentence can be understood as

"His only success was being in the right place at the right time"