# What is the active voice of this sentence: "I was annoyed by Mary wanting to tell everybody what to do"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the active voice of this sentence, please tell me.

“I was annoyed by Mary wanting to tell everybody what to do”

Comment: You must tell us what exactly you don't understand. "I was annoyed" or  "by Mary wanting" or "to tell everybody" or "what to do"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't explain the nature of the poster's difficulty with the quoted sentence.

Comment: what is the meaning of "what to do" in this sentence

Comment: I only came back to see what happened and saw your comment. Sigh... sometimes I forget to add this bit: you must edit the question and clarify IN  your question. To communicate directly with someone, write @username e.g. @ Mari-Lou (no space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was angry. What made me angry was the behaviour of Mary. She was trying to give everyone commands.

*To be annoyed by something* means *to be angry because of something*

the *something* in this case is *Mary wanting*. So it is not the person that annoys, but the behaviour of that person